# syntax of using lapply when using try

Tags: r, try-catch, lapply

I'm using try() to catch errors in an lapply() call.

To use the example from here

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html#condition-handling

```
elements <- list(1:10, c(-1, 10), c(T, F), letters)
results <- lapply(elements, function(x) try(log(x), silent = T))
```

Warning message:
In log(x) : NaNs produced

Using that syntax try catches the errors and produces an output, results.

But if the second line is coded like this it fails. I'm am just wondering why.

```
results <- lapply(elements, try(log))
```

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NaNs produced

I know that I can compose functions and lapply still works with the above syntax. for example

```
f <- function(x) x
g <- function (x) x
x <- c(1:5)
lapply(x, f(g))
```

What is special about "try" in this case that makes it necessary to explicitly call the variable x?

Comment: `results <- lapply(elements, try(log))` makes no sense, really. the very next thing after `elements` is a function that is expected to be run on the parameter. do `try(log)` in R console. It returns the `log` function and that fails on that data. Perhaps `tlog <- function(x) try(log(x), silent=TRUE) ;results <- lapply(elements, tlog)` is what you should do to avoid the anonymous function call.

Comment: `try` evaluates the expression. `identical(try(log), log)` returns `TRUE` and `identical(function(x) try(log(x)), try(log))` returns 'FALSE`

Comment: try evaluates the expression, you can't compose it since you will first execute log and then try ... which will give an error. Try operate on the whole block you give it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Meta question: can one of these be made into the answer.